# Scrapy not scraping content but works in shell

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to scrap items with `Scrapy 0.22` and this code is not working when i call it "`scrapy crawl events_cinema`" - it shows tech information and no scraped content (Crawled 0 pages .... etc).

The problem is when i test xpath in scrapy shell it works, i mean `"sel.xpath("//a[@class='title_link']/text()").extract()"` shows correct results.

I used the same approach to other site and it works, but here I cannot figure out what is wrong.

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from events_rostov.items import EventsRostovItem
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor


class EventsCinemaSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "events_cinema"
    allowed_domains = ["afisha.161.ru"]
    start_urls = ["http://afisha.161.ru/afisha/cinema/"]

    def parse_items(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        #movies = sel.xpath("//td[@class='event_container']")
        #items = []
        #for movie in movies:
        item = EventsRostovItem()
        item["title"] = sel.xpath("//a[@class='title_link']/text()").extract()
        item["link"] = sel.xpath("//a[@class='title_link']/@href").extract()
            #items.append(item)
        return item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably meant to use `Spider` and not `CrawlerSpider`, otherwise you'd have to add some rules to it, also note that `Spider` default function is `parse` and not `parse_items`